# Sorting rss feeds by publish date in android

Tags: android, sqlite, rss-reader

In my android application i am displaying the RSS feeds in a listview. I am parsing the xml file and storing the data in sqlite database. I want to disply the listview from the most recent feed. How to sort the list by publish date? Can we do it using query?

Comment: Post data what you getting in RSS? and How you inserting into the db?

Comment: get sorted data from db and then add to listview

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList Sorting technique. In the following code, list being your ArrayList of RSSObject and getPublishDate() function as your getter function of RSSObject class.

`Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<RSSObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(RSSObjectr1, RSSObject2) {
        return r1.getPublishDate().compareTo(r2.getPublishDate());
    }
});`